# AVL dictionary implementation

Tags: c++, object-oriented

I have implemented a dictionary with an AVL tree, and here is the code and I need help improving it.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>


using namespace std;

class NoSuchKeyExeption {};

template<typename k, typename t>
class dictionary
{
private:
    struct element
    {
        k key;
        t data;
        unsigned height;
        unsigned level;
        element* left;
        element* right;
    };
    element* root;
    unsigned size;

    bool pinsert(element* ptr, const k &key, const t &data,element* parent);

    bool pinsert_pseudo(element* ptr, element* toadd, element* parent);

    element* pcopy(const element* ptr);

    void pinsert_rec(const element* ptr);

    void clear(element* ptr);

    bool pexists(element* ptr, const k& key)const;

    ostream & printos(ostream & os,element* ptr)const;

    ostream & printosdes(ostream & os,element* ptr)const;

    unsigned pheight(const element* ptr)const;

    void calclvls(element* ptr, unsigned lvl, vector<element*> &storage, unsigned & maxlvl)const;

    element* find(const k &key, element* ptr, element*& parent)const;

    void find(element* ptr, vector<k> &keys)const;

    void find(const t &data, element* ptr, vector<k> &keys)const;

    void find(element* ptr, list<k> &keys)const;

    void find(const t &data, element* ptr, list<k> &keys)const;

    element* findrep(element* ptr, bool dir, element*& parent)const;

    element* balance(element* ptr);

    void premove(const element* ptr);

    bool premove(const k &key, element* ptr, element* parent);

    bool comparator(const element* ptr)const;

    inline void newheight(element* ptr);

public:

    dictionary();
    dictionary(const dictionary<k,t> & copy);
    ~dictionary();
    dictionary<k,t> & operator=(const dictionary<k,t> & copy);

    template<typename u, typename i>
    friend dictionary<u,i> operator+(const dictionary<u,i> & add1, const dictionary<u,i> & add2);
    template<typename u, typename i>
    friend dictionary<u,i> operator-(const dictionary<u,i> & subtract1, const dictionary<u,i> & subtract2);

    dictionary<k,t> & operator+=(const dictionary<k,t> & add)
    {
        *this=*this+add;
        return *this;
    };

    dictionary<k,t> & operator-=(const dictionary<k,t> & subtract)
    {
        *this=*this-subtract;
        return *this;
    };


    void clear();
    t& getData(const k& key)const;
    vector<k> vgetKeys()const;
    vector<k> vgetKeys(const t& data)const;
    list<k> lgetKeys()const;
    list<k> lgetKeys(const t& data)const;


    unsigned int getSize()
    {
        return size;
    };

    bool empty()const
    {
        if(!root)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    };

    bool insert(const k &key, const t &data);

    bool remove(const k &key);

    inline bool exists(const k &key)const;

    bool changeKey(const k &keyfrom,const k &keyto);

    void printTree()const;

    template<typename u, typename i>
    friend bool operator==(const dictionary<u,i> & check1,const dictionary<u,i> & check2);

    template<typename u, typename i>
    friend bool operator!=(const dictionary<u,i> & check1,const dictionary<u,i> & check2);

    template<typename u, typename i>
    friend ostream & operator<< (ostream & os, const dictionary<u,i> & toprint);

    void printDescend(ostream & os)const;
};

//MAI JEWELRY
template<typename k, typename t>
bool dictionary<k,t>::pinsert(element* ptr, const k &key, const t &data,element* parent)
{
    if(root==nullptr)
    {
        element* temp = new element;
        temp->key=key;
        temp->data=data;
        temp->height=1;

        temp->left=nullptr;
        temp->right=nullptr;
        root=temp;
        size=1;
        return true;
    }
    if(ptr->key<key)
    {
        if(ptr->right==nullptr)
        {
            element * temp=new element;
            temp->key=key;
            temp->data=data;
            temp->height=1;

            temp->left=nullptr;
            temp->right=nullptr;

            ptr->right=temp;
            size++;
            newheight(ptr);
            return true;
        }
        if(pinsert(ptr->right,key,data,ptr))
        {
            newheight(ptr);
            if(parent)
            {
                if(parent->right==ptr)
                    parent->right=balance(ptr);
                else
                    parent->left=balance(ptr);
            }
            else
                root=balance(ptr);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    else if(key<ptr->key)
    {
        if(ptr->left==nullptr)
        {
            element * temp=new element;
            temp->key=key;
            temp->data=data;
            temp->height=1;

            temp->left=nullptr;
            temp->right=nullptr;

            ptr->left=temp;
            size++;
            newheight(ptr);
            return true;
        }
        if(pinsert(ptr->left,key,data,ptr))
        {
            newheight(ptr);
            if(parent)
            {
                if(parent->right==ptr)
                    parent->right=balance(ptr);
                else
                    parent->left=balance(ptr);
            }
            else
                root=balance(ptr);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;

    }
    return false;
}


template<typename k, typename t>
bool dictionary<k,t>::pinsert_pseudo(element* ptr, element* toadd, element* parent)
{
    if(root==nullptr)
    {
        toadd->left=nullptr;
        toadd->right=nullptr;
        toadd->height=1;
        root=toadd;
        size++;
        return true;
    }
    if(ptr->key<toadd->key)
    {
        if(ptr->right==nullptr)
        {
            toadd->height=1;

            toadd->left=nullptr;
            toadd->right=nullptr;

            ptr->right=toadd;
            size++;
            newheight(ptr);
            //balance(root);
            return true;
        }
        if(pinsert_pseudo(ptr->right,toadd,ptr))
        {
            newheight(ptr);
            if(parent)
                if(parent->right==ptr)
                    parent->right=balance(ptr);
                else
                    parent->left=balance(ptr);
            else
                root=balance(ptr);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    else if(toadd->key<ptr->key)
    {
        if(ptr->left==nullptr)
        {
            toadd->height=1;

            toadd->left=nullptr;
            toadd->right=nullptr;

            ptr->left=toadd;
            size++;
            newheight(ptr);
            //balance(root);
            return true;
        }
        if(pinsert_pseudo(ptr->left,toadd,ptr))
        {
            newheight(ptr);
            if(parent)
                if(parent->right==ptr)
                    parent->right=balance(ptr);
                else
                    parent->left=balance(ptr);
            else
                root=balance(ptr);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;

    }
}


template<typename k, typename t>
typename dictionary<k,t>::element* dictionary<k,t>::pcopy(const element* ptr)
{
    if(ptr==nullptr)
        return nullptr;

    element * temp=new element;
    temp->key=ptr->key;
    temp->data=ptr->data;
    temp->height=ptr->height;

    temp->left=pcopy(ptr->left);
    temp->right=pcopy(ptr->right);
    size++;
    return temp;
}


template<typename k, typename t>
void dictionary<k,t>::pinsert_rec(const element* ptr)
{
    if(ptr==nullptr)
        return;
    if(!pexists(root,ptr->key))
        pinsert(root,ptr->key,ptr->data,nullptr);
    pinsert_rec(ptr->left);
    pinsert_rec(ptr->right);
}


template<typename k, typename t>
void dictionary<k,t>::clear(element* ptr)
{
    if(ptr==nullptr)
        return;

    clear(ptr->left);
    clear(ptr->right);
    delete ptr;
    ptr=nullptr;
}


template<typename k, typename t>
bool dictionary<k,t>::pexists(element* ptr, const k& key)const
{
    if(ptr==nullptr)
        return false;

    if(ptr->key==key)
        return true;

    if(pexists(ptr->left,key)||pexists(ptr->right,key))
        return true;
    return false;
}


template<typename k, typename t>
ostream & dictionary<k,t>::printos(ostream & os,element* ptr)const
{
    if(ptr==nullptr)
        return os;
    printos(os,ptr->left);
    os<<"Key:"<<endl<<ptr->key<<endl<<"Data:"<<endl<<ptr->data<<endl;
    printos(os,ptr->right);
    return os;
}


template<typename k, typename t>
ostream & dictionary<k,t>::printosdes(ostream & os,element* ptr)const
{
    if(ptr==nullptr)
        return os;
    printosdes(os,ptr->right);
    os<<"Key:"<<endl<<ptr->key<<endl<<"Data:"<<endl<<ptr->data<<endl;
    printosdes(os,ptr->left);
    return os;
}


template<typename k, typename t>
unsigned dictionary<k,t>::pheight(const element* ptr)const
{
    if(ptr==nullptr)
        return 0;
    unsigned l=pheight(ptr->left);
    unsigned r=pheight(ptr->right);
    if(l>r)
        return l+1;
    else
        return r+1;
}


template<typename k, typename t>
void dictionary<k,t>::calclvls(element* ptr, unsigned lvl, vector<element*> &storage, unsigned & maxlvl)const
{
    if(ptr==nullptr)
        return;
    ptr->level=++lvl;
    storage.push_back(ptr);
    if(maxlvl<lvl)
        maxlvl=lvl;
    calclvls(ptr->left,lvl,storage,maxlvl);
    calclvls(ptr->right,lvl,storage,maxlvl);
}


template<typename k, typename t>
typename dictionary<k,t>::element* dictionary<k,t>::find(const k &key,element* ptr,element*& parent)const
{
    if(ptr==nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    if(ptr->key==key)
        return ptr;
    parent=ptr;
    element* lrptr=find(key,ptr->left,parent);
    if(lrptr==nullptr)
    {
        parent=ptr;
        lrptr=find(key,ptr->right,parent);
    }
    return lrptr;
}


template<typename k, typename t>
void dictionary<k,t>::find(element* ptr, vector<k> &keys)const
{
    if(ptr==nullptr)
        return;
    keys.push_back(ptr->key);

    find(ptr->left,keys);
    find(ptr->right,keys);
}


template<typename k, typename t>
void dictionary<k,t>::find(const t &data, element* ptr, vector<k> &keys)const
{
    if(ptr==nullptr)
        return;
    if(ptr->data==data)
        keys.push_back(ptr->key);

    find(data,ptr->left,keys);
    find(data,ptr->right,keys);
}


template<typename k, typename t>
void dictionary<k,t>::find(element* ptr, list<k> &keys)const
{
    if(ptr==nullptr)
        return;
    keys.push_back(ptr->key);

    find(ptr->left,keys);
    find(ptr->right,keys);
}


template<typename k, typename t>
void dictionary<k,t>::find(const t &data, element* ptr, list<k> &keys)const
{
    if(ptr==nullptr)
        return;
    if(ptr->data==data)
        keys.push_back(ptr->key);

    find(data,ptr->left,keys);
    find(data,ptr->right,keys);
}


template<typename k, typename t>
typename dictionary<k,t>::element* dictionary<k,t>::findrep(element* ptr,bool dir,element*& parent)const
{
    if(dir)
    {
        if(ptr->right==nullptr)
            return ptr;
        else
        {
            parent=ptr;
            return findrep(ptr->right,true,parent);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(ptr->left==nullptr)
            return ptr;
        else
        {
            parent=ptr;
            return findrep(ptr->left,false,parent);
        }
    }
}


template<typename k, typename t>
typename dictionary<k,t>::element* dictionary<k,t>::balance(element* ptr)
{
    if(ptr==nullptr)
        return nullptr;

    int l=0;
    int r=0;
    if(ptr->left)
        l=ptr->left->height;
    if(ptr->right)
        r=ptr->right->height;
    int balfac=l-r;
    if(balfac<=1&&balfac>=-1)
        return ptr;
    element* swapper;
    if(balfac>1)
    {
        swapper=ptr->left;

        if(ptr->left->right)
        {
            ptr->left=swapper->right;
            swapper->right=swapper->right->left;
            ptr->left->left=swapper;

            newheight(swapper);
            newheight(ptr->left);
            newheight(ptr);

            swapper=ptr->left;
        }

        ptr->left=swapper->right;
        swapper->right=ptr;

        newheight(ptr);
        newheight(swapper);

        if(root==ptr)
            root=swapper;
        return swapper;
    }
    else
    {
        swapper=ptr->right;

        if(ptr->right->left)
        {
            ptr->right=swapper->left;
            swapper->left=swapper->left->right;
            ptr->right->right=swapper;

            newheight(swapper);
            newheight(ptr->right);
            newheight(ptr);

            swapper=ptr->right;
        }

        ptr->right=swapper->left;
        swapper->left=ptr;

        newheight(ptr);
        newheight(swapper);

        if(root==ptr)
            root=swapper;
        return swapper;
    }
}


template<typename k, typename t>
void dictionary<k,t>::premove(const element* ptr)
{
    if(ptr==nullptr)
        return;
    remove(ptr->key);
    premove(ptr->right);
    premove(ptr->left);
}


template<typename k, typename t>
bool dictionary<k,t>::premove(const k &key, element* remptr, element* parent)
{
    if(remptr==nullptr)
        return false;
    if(remptr->key!=key)
    {
        if(key<remptr->key)
        {
            if(premove(key,remptr->left,remptr))
            {
                newheight(remptr);
                if(parent)
                    if(parent->right==remptr)
                        parent->right=balance(remptr);
                    else
                        parent->left=balance(remptr);
                else
                    balance(remptr);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(premove(key,remptr->right,remptr))
            {
                newheight(remptr);
                if(parent)
                    if(parent->right==remptr)
                        parent->right=balance(remptr);
                    else
                        parent->left=balance(remptr);
                else
                    balance(remptr);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(remptr->right==nullptr&&remptr->left==nullptr)
    {
        if(parent)
        {
            if(parent->right==remptr)
                parent->right=nullptr;
            else
                parent->left=nullptr;
        }
        else
            root=nullptr;
        delete remptr;
        size--;
        return true;
    }
    if(remptr->right==nullptr||remptr->left==nullptr)
    {
        if(parent)
        {
            if(parent->right==remptr)
            {
                if(remptr->right==nullptr)
                    parent->right=remptr->left;
                else
                    parent->right=remptr->right;
            }
            else
            {
                if(remptr->right==nullptr)
                    parent->left=remptr->left;
                else
                    parent->left=remptr->right;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(remptr->right==nullptr)
                root=remptr->left;
            else
                root=remptr->right;
        }
        delete remptr;
        size--;
        return true;
    }

    element* repparent=nullptr;
    element* repptr=findrep(remptr->right,false,repparent);

    if(parent)
    {
        if(parent->right==remptr)
            parent->right=repptr;
        else
            parent->left=repptr;
    }
    else
        root=repptr;
    repptr->left=remptr->left;
    if(remptr->right!=repptr)
    {
        repparent->left=repptr->right;
        repptr->right=remptr->right;
    }
    delete remptr;
    size--;

    return true;
}


template<typename k, typename t>
bool dictionary<k,t>::comparator(const element* ptr)const
{
    if(ptr==nullptr&&root==nullptr)
        return true;
    if(ptr==nullptr)
        return true;
    if(!pexists(root,ptr->key))
        return false;
    if(comparator(ptr->left)&&comparator(ptr->right))
        return true;
    return false;
}


template<typename k, typename t>
void dictionary<k,t>::newheight(element* ptr)
{
    if(ptr->right||ptr->left)
    {
        if(ptr->right&&ptr->left)
            ptr->height=ptr->right->height>ptr->left->height?ptr->right->height+1:ptr->left->height+1;
        else if(ptr->right)
            ptr->height=ptr->right->height+1;
        else
            ptr->height=ptr->left->height+1;
    }
    else
        ptr->height=1;
}


//MAI PUBLICS
template<typename k, typename t>
dictionary<k,t>::dictionary()
{
    root=nullptr;
    size=0;
}


template<typename k, typename t>
dictionary<k,t>::dictionary(const dictionary<k,t> & copy)
{
    size=0;
    root=pcopy(copy.root);
}


template<typename k, typename t>
dictionary<k,t>::~dictionary()
{
    clear(root);
    size=0;
}


template<typename k, typename t>
dictionary<k,t> & dictionary<k,t>::operator=(const dictionary<k,t> & copy)
{
    if(this==&copy)
        return *this;
    clear(root);
    size=0;
    root=pcopy(copy.root);
}
template<typename k, typename t>
dictionary<k,t> operator+(const dictionary<k,t> & add1, const dictionary<k,t> & add2)
{
    dictionary<k,t> temp;
    temp.root = temp.pcopy(add1.root);
    temp.pinsert_rec(add2.root);
    return temp;
}


template<typename k, typename t>
dictionary<k,t> operator-(const dictionary<k,t> & subtract1, const dictionary<k,t> & subtract2)
{
    dictionary<k,t> temp;
    temp.root = temp.pcopy(subtract1.root);
    temp.premove(subtract2.root);
    return temp;
}


template<typename k, typename t>
void dictionary<k,t>::clear()
{
    clear(root);
    size=0;
    root=nullptr;
}


template<typename k, typename t>
t& dictionary<k,t>::getData(const k& key)const
{
    element *ptr,*parent;
    ptr=find(key,root,parent);
    if(ptr==nullptr)
        throw NoSuchKeyExeption();
    return ptr->data;
}


template<typename k, typename t>
vector<k> dictionary<k,t>::vgetKeys()const
{
    vector<k> keys;
    find(root,keys);
    return keys;
}


template<typename k, typename t>
vector<k> dictionary<k,t>::vgetKeys(const t& data)const
{
    vector<k> keys;
    find(data,root,keys);
    return keys;
}


template<typename k, typename t>
list<k> dictionary<k,t>::lgetKeys()const
{
    list<k> keys;
    find(root,keys);
    return keys;
}


template<typename k, typename t>
list<k> dictionary<k,t>::lgetKeys(const t& data)const
{
    list<k> keys;
    find(data,root,keys);
    return keys;
}


template<typename k, typename t>
bool dictionary<k,t>::insert(const k &key, const t &data)
{
    if(pexists(root,key))
        return false;

    return pinsert(root,key,data,nullptr);
}


template<typename k, typename t>
bool dictionary<k,t>::remove(const k &key)
{
    return premove(key,root,nullptr);
}


template<typename k, typename t>
bool dictionary<k,t>::exists(const k &key)const
{
    return pexists(root,key);
}


template<typename k, typename t>
bool dictionary<k,t>::changeKey(const k &keyfrom,const k &keyto)
{
    if(pexists(root,keyto))
        return false;

    element* remptr;
    element* parent=nullptr;
    remptr = find(keyfrom,root,parent);

    //copypasta from remove method
    {
        if(remptr==nullptr)
            return false;
        else if(remptr->right==nullptr&&remptr->left==nullptr)
        {
            if(parent)
            {
                if(parent->right==remptr)
                    parent->right=nullptr;
                else
                    parent->left=nullptr;
            }
            else
                root=nullptr;
            size--;
            balance(root);
        }
        else if(remptr->right==nullptr||remptr->left==nullptr)
        {
            if(parent)
            {
                if(parent->right==remptr)
                {
                    if(remptr->right==nullptr)
                        parent->right=remptr->left;
                    else
                        parent->right=remptr->right;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(remptr->right==nullptr)
                        parent->left=remptr->left;
                    else
                        parent->left=remptr->right;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(remptr->right==nullptr)
                    root=remptr->left;
                else
                    root=remptr->right;
            }
            size--;
            balance(root);
        }
        else
        {
            element* repparent=nullptr;
            element* repptr=findrep(remptr->right,false,repparent);

            if(parent)
            {
                if(parent->right==remptr)
                    parent->right=repptr;
                else
                    parent->left=repptr;
            }
            else
                root=repptr;
            repptr->left=remptr->left;
            if(remptr->right!=repptr)
            {
                repparent->left=repptr->right;
                repptr->right=remptr->right;
            }
            size--;
            balance(root);
        }
    }

    remptr->key=keyto;
    pinsert_pseudo(root,remptr,nullptr);
}


template<typename k, typename t>
void dictionary<k,t>::printTree()const
{
    vector<element*> storage;
    unsigned maxlvl=0;
    calclvls(root,0,storage,maxlvl);
    cout<<"size: "<<storage.size()<<endl;
    cout<<"maxlvl: "<<maxlvl<<endl;

    for(int i=1; i<=maxlvl; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<storage.size(); j++)
        {
            if(storage[j]->level==i)
            {
                cout<<storage[j]->key<<"  "<<storage[j]->height;
                cout<<"(";
                if(storage[j]->right)
                    cout<<storage[j]->right->key;
                cout<<",";
                if(storage[j]->left)
                    cout<<storage[j]->left->key;
                cout<<")"<<"  |  ";
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}


template<typename u, typename i>
bool operator==(const dictionary<u,i> & check1,const dictionary<u,i> & check2)
{
    return check1.comparator(check2.root);
}


template<typename u, typename i>
bool operator!=(const dictionary<u,i> & check1,const dictionary<u,i> & check2)
{
    return !check1.comparator(check2.root);
}


template<typename u, typename i>
ostream & operator<< (ostream & os, const dictionary<u,i> & toprint)
{
    toprint.printos(os,toprint.root);
    return os;
}


template<typename k, typename t>
void dictionary<k,t>::printDescend(ostream & os)const
{
    printosdes(os,root);
}

int main()
{

    dictionary<int,string> lol;
    lol.insert(5,"dont care");
    lol.insert(8,"dont care");
    lol.insert(3,"dont care");
    lol.insert(1,"dont care");
    lol.insert(4,"dont care");
    lol.insert(10,"dont care");
    lol.insert(6,"dont care");
    lol.insert(12,"dont care");
    lol.insert(11,"dont care");

    lol.insert(7,"dont care");
    lol.insert(13,"dont care");
    lol.insert(2,"dont care");
    lol.printTree();
    lol.remove(8);
    lol.printTree();

    lol.getData(11)="well what do you know it works";

    dictionary<int,string> lol2;
    lol2+=lol;

    cout<<(lol2==lol)<<endl;

    cout<<lol<<endl;
    lol.printDescend(cout);


    lol2.insert(-10,"hi im new here");
    lol2.insert(23,"hi im new here");
    lol2.insert(7,"hi im new here");
    lol2.insert(-1,"hi im new here");



    cout<<(lol2==lol)<<endl;

    lol2.changeKey(7,1000);

    cout<<"Start keys found in order"<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<lol2.vgetKeys().size(); i++)
        cout<<lol2.vgetKeys()[i]<<endl;
    cout<<"End keys found in order"<<endl;

    cout<<"Start keys found in order"<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<lol2.vgetKeys("dont care").size(); i++)
        cout<<lol2.vgetKeys("dont care")[i]<<endl;
    cout<<"End keys found in order"<<endl;

    lol2.changeKey(lol2.vgetKeys("dont care")[0],666);

    dictionary<int,string> lol3 = lol2+lol;
    cout<<"we got here"<<endl;
    (lol2-lol).printTree();
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<(lol2-lol).getSize();
    cout<<endl;
    lol.printTree();
    cout<<endl;
    lol2.printTree();
    cout<<lol2.getData(11)<<endl;
    cout<<lol2.vgetKeys("hiim new here").size()<<endl;
    cout<<lol2.lgetKeys("dont care").size()<<endl;

    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<"------------End Normal Testing------------------"<<endl;


    srand(time(nullptr));
    lol3.clear();
    int loops = 10000;
    cout<<"the loop length is: "<<loops<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<loops; i++)
        lol3.insert(rand(),"does it matter");
    for(int i=0; i<loops; i++)
        lol3.remove(rand());
    // lol3.printTree();
    //cout<<lol3<<endl;
    cout<<"the size is: "<<lol3.getSize()<<endl;

}
```

Could you please help me improve it

Comment: What is wrong with it and what do you think needs to be improved?

Comment: if I knew I wouldn't have asked